# Data structure with constant time search and unique indices

Tags: c, search, data-structures, hash

I want to construct a data structure when given a 80-bit key (unsigned char), it should store that key and its corresponding value at a unique index (dense indexing) since an index is usually 32-bit size  but not 80-bit. And should provide constant-time (worst case) search functionality.

If I am correct a hash table with open addressing collision mechanism can achieve this, right?
And/Or is there any other better data structure to achieve these objectives?

Note: My 80-bit key is of type unsigned char since I'm working in C.

Comment: Is it fair to assume your keys have a uniform distribution?

Comment: Yes, because they are generated from sha-256 cryptographic functions

Comment: If you are using SHA256 you should achieve constant time search although it wouldn't be for the "worst case" in the literal sense, since in theory if you had many collisions it would get very bad, but if you managed that it is likely to be more interesting than whatever you are trying to accomplish since we have yet to find any collisions for SHA256(according to wikipedia)

Comment: Yes, just provide a table 2-3x the size of the number of keys, if you can afford it.

Comment: As the key length is a small constant, a trie would be worst-case O(1) time in theory - even the best hash table is "only" *average* O(1) - and pretty fast in practice, though it might incur several cache misses where a good hash table might only incur one.

Comment: @delnan my key length is 80-bits but constant, is that okay in a trie to achieve unique indexing for all keys? And can you tell me what do you mean by cache misses?